# How to get indexed DESC sorting in MySQL 5.7?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, database-design

Newer versions of MySQL, notably v8.0, support DESC indices. Unfortunately, due to my cloud hosting platform, I am stuck with MySQL 5.7 and its ASC indices.

From my understanding, indices can drastically speed up sorting. I have a table with millions of rows and the majority of my sorting is DESC.

**Is there any way to index the columns I'm sorting regularly to achieve blazingly fast DESC sorts?** The first thought that comes to mind is storing the integer values I would like to sort on as negatives.

Comment: The negative value is your best bet.  I don't know why MySQL doesn't know how to read the index backwards.  It is not that big an innovation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Apparently MySQL is smart enough to read the index backwards.

Comment: . . If it does, then the descending sort should use the index.

Comment: There is possibly a gain if an index is being used to sort by one column ascending and the second column of the same index descending. But even then you're doing a little extra scanning on something that is memory and possibly even cpu d-cache. @Rage want to show some queries, table structures (`SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}`), `EXPLAIN {query}`, query time measurements and see if a second "fake" desc index using [generated columns indexed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html) makes a difference?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/10/20/mysql-8-0-descending-indexes-can-speedup-your-queries/

Apparently MySQL is smart enough to read the index backwards. However, the index can only be read backwards if all the ORDER BYs are of the same type. The second you mix DESC and ASC in MySQL 5.7, is the second you die waiting for the query to finish.